# Elasticsearch unable to start - Permission issue

Tags: java, linux, elasticsearch

I installed elasticsearch-5.0 on a new machine with CentOS 6. It is not coming up after installation. Below is the error I am getting -

All the below commands were issued as root

Installation is carried out using the rpm file with the following command

```
$# yum install elasticsearch-5.0.0.rpm
```

Adding the elasticsearch to start after every boot

```
$# chkconfig --add elasticsearch
```

Starting elasticsearch as a service

```
$# service elasticsearch start
```

Output from console

```
Starting elasticsearch: 2016-12-09 01:52:44,385 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:421)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:403)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)

2016-12-09 01:52:44,390 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5ccddd20] unable to create manager for [/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@1ed1993a[pattern=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.10000m%n]]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        ... 23 more

2016-12-09 01:52:44,402 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_deprecation.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:421)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:403)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)

2016-12-09 01:52:44,403 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5ccddd20] unable to create manager for [/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_deprecation.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@4690b489[pattern=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_deprecation-%i.log.gz, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(size=1073741824)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=4), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c{1.}] %marker%.10000m%n]]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        ... 23 more

2016-12-09 01:52:44,408 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:421)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:403)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)

2016-12-09 01:52:44,409 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5ccddd20] unable to create manager for [/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@3c22fc4c[pattern=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_search_slowlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %marker%.10000m%n]]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        ... 23 more

2016-12-09 01:52:44,414 main ERROR Unable to create file /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:421)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:403)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)

2016-12-09 01:52:44,415 main ERROR Unable to invoke factory method in class class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:918)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:858)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:850)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:479)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:219)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:231)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:496)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:116)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.logging.LogConfigurator.configure(LogConfigurator.java:83)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:249)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:112)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:103)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.SettingCommand.execute(SettingCommand.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:96)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:62)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:80)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:73)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ManagerFactory [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory@5ccddd20] unable to create manager for [/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog.log] with data [org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$FactoryData@3aefe5e5[pattern=/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_index_indexing_slowlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log, append=true, bufferedIO=true, bufferSize=8192, policy=CompositeTriggeringPolicy(policies=[TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy(nextRolloverMillis=0, interval=1, modulate=true)]), strategy=DefaultRolloverStrategy(min=1, max=7), advertiseURI=null, layout=[%d{ISO8601}][%-5p][%-25c] %marker%.10000m%n]]
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:75)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:81)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:103)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender.createAppender(RollingFileAppender.java:191)
        ... 23 more

2016-12-09 01:52:44,880 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2016-12-09 01:52:44,880 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2016-12-09 01:52:44,880 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2016-12-09 01:52:44,881 main ERROR Null object returned for RollingFile in Appenders.
2016-12-09 01:52:44,881 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "rolling" for logger config "root"
2016-12-09 01:52:44,881 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_indexing_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.indexing.slowlog.index"
2016-12-09 01:52:44,882 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "index_search_slowlog_rolling" for logger config "index.search.slowlog"
2016-12-09 01:52:44,882 main ERROR Unable to locate appender "deprecation_rolling" for logger config "org.elasticsearch.deprecation"
                                                           [FAILED]
```

Here is the permissions set for /var/log/elasticsearch directory

```
 drwxr-xr-x  2 elasticsearch elasticsearch    4096 Dec 09 10:40 elasticsearch
```

/var/log/elasticsearch is owned by elasticsearch:elasticsearch and it's permissions are 755. Suggestions or answers for solving this problem is appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the commands you ran to install? I'm wondering if the problem is during the install, as my user:group and permissions are the same, and mine works.

Comment: Edited the question as per your suggestion.

Comment: Shoot, I can't replicate it using JDK 1.8, CentoOS 6.7, and elasticsearch 5.0.0. The only difference in the installation is I didn't run as root, but I did run sudo commands to reach it. If you run cat /etc/passwd | grep elasticsearch , does anything come back?

Comment: elasticsearch:x:495:492:elasticsearch user:/home/elasticsearch:/sbin/nologin

Comment: Thanks for the support. Finally found out with external help that the logs directory does not have permission for writing where as elasticsearch folder inside log directory does.

Answer (score 1):

As the logs suggest, it seems seems like ElasticSearch does not have write entitlements to the directory.

Verify if the user you are running ElasticSearch with has access to write to that folder/directory?

Comment: Seems elasticsearch has the necessary permissions.

Comment: /var/log/elasticsearch has all the permissions. However its parent's directory doesn't have necessary permissions. Solved.

Comment: @helloworld I'm having the same issue, can you clarify the steps you took to resolve it? I've tried adjusting the permissions for /var/log/elasticsearch at every level of the tree using `sudo chown myusername /path/`

Comment: ok fixed it, turns out under debian elasticsearch runs as a user called `elasticsearch` - this is who I needed to assign permissions to for writing the logs.

Answer (score 0):

You check the `path.data` permission, it seems that you have to change it to 777.

Answer (score 0):

Update `/etc/sysconfig/docker` with below for OPTION key -

```
--selinux-enabled=false
```